# android: ViewPager: How to get the scroll position of the view inside the view pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

ViewPager.getScrollY() gets me the scroll Y position of the view pager itself but how to get the scroll Y position of the current view inside the view pager? Thank you!

Comment: Call `getScrollY()` on the current view inside the `ViewPager`, I imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewPager.getChildAt(viewPager.getCurrentItem()).getScrollY())
```

`viewPager.getCurrentItem()` gets the position of the active open view inside the view pager. `viewPager.getChildAt()` gives the actual view at a given index. Once you get the active view, you need to call `getScrollY()` to get the scroll position of the active view in the view pager.

Comment: just added more info.

Comment: Why is it "Y" ? When do you get a value of the Y coordinate for a viewPager? Also, how come when I use "X", I always get 0 ?